# take a word from the user and prints it as shown below. Enter the word: Word d rd ord Word

Tags: c++, string

Write a C++ code that takes a word from the user and prints it as shown below.

```
Enter the word: Word d rd ord Word
```

I attempted to solve this question as;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    cout << "Enter the word: ";
    cin>>word;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < word.length(); j++) {
            cout << word[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives result as;

```
word
ord
rd
d
```

How can I change this code to give result as;

```
d 
rd
ord
word
```

Comment: Perhaps the inner loop should iterate from the back to the start of the string?

Comment: Hi Salih! Have you thought about what your `word[j]` does and how it relates to your `for(int j…` loop? This feels like you're very close!

Comment: @Salih Sultan This statement cin>>word; reads only the first string "Word" from the input stream. You need to use getline.

Comment: The headline implies otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the expected output, you can make the outer loop loop from `word.length() - 1` down to `0` instead:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>   // std::size_t
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter the word:";

    if (std::string word; std::cin >> word) {
        for (auto i = word.length(); i--;) {                   // <- here
            for (std::size_t j = i; j < word.length(); j++) {
                std::cout << word[j];
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I changed `i` and `j` to be (`unsigned`) `std::size_t`s instead of (`signed`) `int`. `std::size_t` is the correct type to use with the `length()` member function.

You could also simplify it by skipping the inner loop completely:

```cpp
        for (auto i = word.length(); i--;) {
            // supply a char* where to start printing from:
            std::cout << &word[i] << '\n';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters this statement

```
cin>>word;
```

reads only one word. That is if you will enter as shown in your question

```
Enter the word: Word d rd ord Word
```

then the variable `word` will contain only one string `"Word"` instead of the typed full string `"Word d rd ord Word"`.

Instead of the operator `>>` you need to use standard function `std::getline`.

Otherwise this line in your question

```
Enter the word: Word d rd ord Word
```

does not make sense.

it seems you need to output words in the entered string `"Word d rd ord Word"` in ascending order by the length of words contained in the string without duplicates.

This can be easy done using standard container `std::set`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::string word;

    std::cout << "Enter the word: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, word );

    auto cmp = []( const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2 )
    {
        return s1.length() < s2.length();
    };

    std::set<std::string, decltype( cmp )> s( cmp );

    std::stringstream iss( word );

    for (std::string w; iss >> w; )
    {
        s.insert( w );
    }

    for (const auto &w : s)
    {
        std::cout << w << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Enter the word: Word d rd ord Word
d
rd
ord
Word
```

If instead of this input

```
Enter the word: Word d rd ord Word
```

you mean the following input

```
Enter the word: Word
```

and want to output sub-strings starting from the end of the entered string then it can be done with only one for loop and class `std::string_view` the folloing way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    std::string word;

    std::cout << "Enter the word: ";
    std::cin >> word;

    for (auto n = word.length(); n != 0; )
    {
        std::cout << std::string_view( word.c_str() + --n ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is similar as shown above (except the entered string) though the programs do different things

```
Enter the word: Word
r
rd
ord
Word
```

Answer (score 0):

This becomes a lot easier if you get into the habit of *not* using variable names like `i` and `j`, but stick with names that *mean* something to you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    cout << "Enter the word: ";
    cin>>word;
        for (int starting_point = 0; starting_point < word.length(); starting_point++) {
        for (int position = starting_point; position < word.length(); position++) {
            cout << word[position];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do you now spot why you're not counting letters backwards? It's the same code, but I used better names.

I'll give you a completely different solution, just to illustrate the point of *saying what you mean*; maybe it's enough to help you fix your own code!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    std::string word;
    std::cout << "Enter the word: ";
    std::cin >> word;

    auto current_begin = word.end();
    while (current_begin != word.begin()) {
        --current_begin;
        std::cout << std::string_view(current_begin, word.end()) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```